# ExpressionEngine beta 2.10

Tags: update

I heard about ExpressionEngine beta 2.10.0 for developers with the Zoo Visitor, and DevDemon Updater updates.

Does someone knows what will are the new features of EE 2.10.0 ?

Comment: A subversion release probably has mostly bug fixes and small features. Tweet @EllisLab and maybe they'll PM you some details! Also, please don't upgrade a production site to a beta release, you are asking for downtime if you do.

Answer (score 1):

No new features - [view changelog](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-10-0).

EE v3 is being released this year and the developers confirmed that there are no more features to be released in the v2 family, it will only be security additions and bug fixes.

Comment: Yes thanks EE 2.10 is ready for downloading!!